# Python : ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Hello I have an error in my code but I don't understand the problem. You can help me ?
Here is the error :  ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

```
# Combat
nike = None
tour = "tour.png"
win = "win.png"
sort = "sort.png"
end = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(win)

while nike == None:
    try:
     nike = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(tour)
     pyautogui.press("b")
     attack = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("attack.png",confidence=0.7)
     pyautogui.moveTo(attack)
     pyautogui.click()
     pyautogui.press("b")
     attack = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("attack.png",confidence=0.7)
     pyautogui.moveTo(attack)
     pyautogui.click()
     pyautogui.press("f1")
     end = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(win)
     if end != None:
      pyautogui.press("enter")
     break
```

Comment: In which line did *SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing* appear?

Comment: A `try` needs a matching `except`.

Comment: Can you show us the full error traceback for better understanding!

Comment: @Axe319 Or `finally`. (For some reason, you can't have an `else` clause without at least one preceding `except` clause.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code indentation is not according to the standard, also catch block is mandatory with try block fixing these things makes your code some thing like below

```
# Combat
nike = None
tour = "tour.png"
win = "win.png"
sort = "sort.png"
end = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(win)

while nike == None:
    try:
        nike = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(tour)
        pyautogui.press("b")
        attack = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("attack.png",confidence=0.7)
        pyautogui.moveTo(attack)
        pyautogui.click()
        pyautogui.press("b")
        attack = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("attack.png",confidence=0.7)
        pyautogui.moveTo(attack)
        pyautogui.click()
        pyautogui.press("f1")
        end = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(win)
        if end != None:
            pyautogui.press("enter")
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Which is running just fine wihtout any EOF file parsing error

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding:

```
except:
  break
```

At the same indent as `try`

Like:

```
# Combat
nike = None
tour = "tour.png"
win = "win.png"
sort = "sort.png"
end = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(win)

while nike == None:
    try:
     nike = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(tour)
     pyautogui.press("b")
     attack = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("attack.png",confidence=0.7)
     pyautogui.moveTo(attack)
     pyautogui.click()
     pyautogui.press("b")
     attack = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("attack.png",confidence=0.7)
     pyautogui.moveTo(attack)
     pyautogui.click()
     pyautogui.press("f1")
     end = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(win)
     if end != None:
      pyautogui.press("enter")
      break
    except:
      break
```